# Jasper Reports dataSource working strange

Tags: java, jdbc, jasper-reports, datasource

I have Jasper Reports project. When I set dataSource parameter like "Code 1", Jasper Reports's PDF file returns empty. But if I set JRResultSetDataSource directly (Code 2) it is working. What is differance below code? I am confused because i thing they are same...

Code 1:

```
JRResultSetDataSource dataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);
```

Code 2:

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JRResultSetDataSource(rs));
```

Comment: Above code seems same. must be other difference between codes. check  jasperprint before converting pdf  contains data or not ?

Comment: In fact I just changed here now it is working, I dont know why